# Punctuation issue on Harvard style

Tags: natbib, punctuation

I have the following style:

> Anderson, E. (1988), 'Transaction costs as determinants of opportunism in integrated and independent sales forces', *Journal of Economic Behavior & Organization* Vol. 9 No. 3, pp. 247-264.

How do I make changes to get the following punctuation format?

> Anderson, E. (1988), “Transaction costs as determinants of opportunism in integrated and independent sales forces”, *Journal of Economic Behavior & Organization*, Vol. 9 No. 3, pp. 247-264.

I use the following codes to import from JabRef

```
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add a [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography) so we can see how you are producing your current output.

Comment: \bibliographystyle{agsm}

\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}

Comment: no it is a different issue